# class keyword in a Kafka function

Tags: java

I am using a a java kafka function inside a spark streaming application

```
JavaInputDStream<Tuple2<String,String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                Tuple2.class,
                kafkaParams,
                fromOffsets,
                messageHandler);
```

The record output is as the type of Tuple2
The above gives me error due to

```
Tuple2.class
```

the error says:

```
The method createDirectStream(JavaStreamingContext, Class<K>, Class<V>, Class<KD>, Class<VD>, Class<R>, Map<String,String>, Map<TopicAndPartition,Long>, Function<MessageAndMetadata<K,V>,R>) in the type KafkaUtils is not applicable for the arguments (JavaStreamingContext, Class<String>, Class<String>, Class<StringDecoder>, Class<StringDecoder>, Class<Tuple2>, Map<String,String>, Map<TopicAndPartition,Long>, Function<MessageAndMetadata<String,String>,Tuple2<String,String>>)
```

How to use class keyword for a Tuple2< String,String>?

Comment: Can you please share the error details ?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Consider Example 7, it would help to resolve the line 
 Tuple2< String,String>, http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils